# Is it possible to compress files which are already in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression

I have a S3 bucket which has wide variety of files. Some of the files are of huge size like 8Gb, 11GB. Biggest one is of 14.6GB.

I was searching for the way compress them. Obviously, i can download them locally and compress them and put it back in bucket. I thought its not good way to achieve it as i have to download the files first which is time consuming process.

Is there any way in AWS cloud services itself using which i can compress the files directly and put them back in S3?

One of the solution i can think of is creating an EC2 instance get the files there and compress and put them back in S3 Bucket.

Are there any better methods i can use?

Answer (score 3):

There is no compression capability provided by Amazon S3.

You should create an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket, then **download/compress/upload** the files.

Network bandwidth varies by **instance type**, so if you find the downloads/uploads running slowly, change to a bigger instance type. Use **spot instances** to make the whole process low-cost.