# What are the classes and interfaces related to zip aws S3 objects?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, zip

I want to write a java program to zip an aws object (file or a directory) in a given location (S3 bucket partition) to another given location. I have done the same task not foe S3 objects but for local disk files and directories. is there any direct way (using a class or interface) to do so?
And i got to read that it can be done by

1. download object to local
2. Zip the downloaded file
3. upload to the desired location

is the practical way to do this. Do anyone have a better idea or the classes and interfaces that can be used for the above steps! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

For steps (1) and (3) in your list, this has examples of how to download and upload objects to S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html.

The classes and interfaces mentioned in the examples are documented here: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/. Scroll down in the top left frame to the S3 packages starting with *software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3*.

For step (2) (zipping the file once downloaded), you could use the code you used for zipping the local files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question has been already answered here -

[Is it possible to compress files which are already in AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779234/is-it-possible-to-compress-files-which-are-already-in-aws-s3)

If you are looking for aws sdk java api for s3 -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html